# Magento 2 Plugin not called

Tags: magento2, controllers, plugin

etc/di.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Customer\Controller\Address\FormPost">
        <plugin name="yourCompanyYourModuleControllerProductView" type="namespace\Customer\Plugin\FormPost" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Plugin/FormPost.php

```
<?php
namespace namespace\Customer\Plugin;
class FormPost {
    public function afterExecute(\Magento\Customer\Controller\Address\FormPost $subject)
    {
        $temp = '';
        $te = '';
    }
}
```

But code is not being called.. any one has idea what could be possible reason for this?
Thanks

Comment: Any error are throw?

Comment: its not throwing any error too... its just not going in Plugin code... I put breakpoint in plugin method...

Comment: Make sure your module name is the same in your registration.php file as it is in your etc/module.xml file. This caused an issue for me.

Comment: It was caching issue.... thanks for ur comments :)

Comment: How do you check if the plugin is getting called?!

Answer (score 0):

You have forgot to pass second argument to function,
pass **$result** as second argument,

**$result is original method return value.**

```
<?php
namespace namespace\Customer\Plugin;
class FormPost {
    public function afterExecute(\Magento\Customer\Controller\Address\FormPost $subject,$result)
    {
        $temp = '';
        $te = '';
        return 'Test '.$result;
    }
}
```

Comment: tried it... it did not work...

Answer (score 0):

My case was forget to Di Compile

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```